# How to set new dataSource and refresh kendo grid with new data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-grid

I have `$scope.addProcessOwner` function in Add owner grid config now when user click on each owner i am creating new array object with `selectedOwners`, Now i want to set  `selectedOwners` as dataSource of selected owner grid.

1- How can i set `selectedOwners` as a dataSource of `selectedOwnerGridOptions` ?

2- How can i refresh selected owner grid once owner is selected from Add owner grid ?

grid.html

Add owner

```
<div kendo-grid="ownerSearch" options="ownerSearchResultGrid"
                    k-rebind="getOwnerSearchResultGrid"></div>
```

selected owner

```
<div kendo-grid="selectedOwner" options="selectedOwnerGridOptions" k-data-source="selectedOwnerGrid"></div>
```

Ctrl.js

```
 var selectedOwners = [];
   $scope.addProcessOwner = function(dataItem){
                var selectedOwner = {
                    fullName: dataItem.fullName,
                    workerKey: dataItem.workerKey,
                    stdId: dataItem.stdId,
                    workEmailAddressText: dataItem.workEmailAddressText
                };
                 var isExists = function(e) {
                  if (e.fullName === selectedOwner.fullName && e.workerKey === selectedOwner.workerKey) {
                      return true;
                  }
                };
                if (!selectedOwners.some(isExists)) {
                  selectedOwners.push(selectedOwner);
                }
                console.log('WORKER DATA',JSON.stringify(selectedOwners));
                $scope.selectedOwnerGrid = selectedOwners;
                $scope.selectedOwnerGridOptions.dataSource.read();
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
$scope.selectedOwnerGrid = selectedOwners;
$scope.selectedOwnerGridOptions.dataSource.read();
```

Try this:

```
$scope.selectedOwnerGridOptions.dataSource.data(selectedOwners);
```

Comment: it adds first owner and also throw error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined` any idea why